# select all from t1 if t1.uniqueNumber != t2.uniqueNumber

Tags: mysql, select

Let me describe my needs....

I have 2 MySQL table of a database. Let me call the table name as stock-in and stock-out. Firstly, I have inserted 15 rows into stock-in with an unique number for each entry as serialno.

```
mysql> select stockin_id, serialno, description from stockin limit 0,15;
+------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| stockin_id | serialno   | description                              |
+------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
|          1 | KDR0000001 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|          2 | KDR0000002 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|          3 | KDR0000003 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|          4 | KDR0000004 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|          5 | KDR0000005 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|          6 | KDR0000006 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|          7 | KDR0000007 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|          8 | KDR0000008 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|          9 | KDR0000009 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|         10 | KDR0000010 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|         11 | T22ALT5786 | PRINTED BRD ASSMBLY                      |
|         12 | TU82956450 | FUNCTIONAL UNIT/GSM DXU-21               |
|         13 | X510239240 | FUNCTIONAL UNIT/GSM DXU-21               |
|         14 | TD36843873 | PRINTED BOARD ASSEMB/RP4-F               |
|         15 | TD36843908 | PRINTED BOARD ASSEMB/RP4-F               |
+------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I have been transferred few products from stock-in products with same serialno which stored in stock-out table as follows-

```
mysql> select stockout_id, serialno, description from stockout limit 0,15;
+------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| stockin_id | serialno   | description                              |
+------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
|          1 | KDR0000001 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|          2 | KDR0000002 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|          3 | KDR0000003 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
|          4 | KDR0000004 | DATA CARRIER/FLASH CARD WITH RBS 2000 SW |
+------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I would like to select the exact ***STOCK-IN HAND*** entries from stock-in. How may i achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    stockin si  
WHERE   NOT EXISTS  (
                        SELECT  1
                        FROM    stockout so 
                        WHERE   si.serialno = so.serialno
                    )
```

OR

```
SELECT  *
FROM    stockin si  
WHERE   si.serialno NOT IN  (
                                SELECT  so.serialno
                                FROM    stockout so 
                            )
```

If you know that the entries in table `stockin` and `stockout` are unique

```
SELECT  *
FROM    stockin si LEFT JOIN
        stockout so ON  si.serialno = so.serialno
WHERE   so.serialno IS NULL
```

I would suggest yopu use the one that makes most sense to you when you read it, and only then start worrying about performance.

Comment: I typically go with either number 1 or number 3. Number 3 if you are using data from the second table, number 1 if not.

Comment: HeidiSQL query time as follows-
#1- /* 0 rows affected, 3,994 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec. (+ 0.094 sec. network) */
#2- /* 0 rows affected, 3,994 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec. (+ 0.094 sec. network) */
#3- /* 0 rows affected, 3,994 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec. (+ 0.156 sec. network) */

So, I am going with #1 and finally a thanks to you.

Comment: Dear @astander, every queries is taking huge time to execute when stockin entries is - 14463 and stockout entries is 19658... Can you suggest me different way to execute this stock-in hand

Comment: Sorry, Pardon please... How may i check indexes on the tables?

Comment: Yeah @astander, problem was in indexing. I have created index for both table and it change dramatically...

`mysql> CREATE INDEX siserialno ON stockin (serialno);`
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.40 sec)`
`Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0`

`mysql> CREATE INDEX soserialno ON stockout (serialno);`
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)`
`Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0`

thanks again dude